# How to opensource a Maven plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have a Maven plugin that I want to share with outside world. Is there an official Maven repository I can deploy this plugin too ? What are the steps involved ?

Any links to documentation much appreciated

I've been reading http://www.sonatype.com/people/2008/11/adding-a-jar-to-a-maven-repository-with-sonatype-nexus/ but this just seems to describe deploying to internal Nexus repository, wheras I want to deploy to an external repo so any user can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend:

- Setting up an account in [Github](http://www.github.com/) in order to have a place to host your source code.
- Setting up an account in Cloudbee's [BuildHive](https://buildhive.cloudbees.com/). This is a free Jenkins CI for Open Source projects. This will test your project on every push to Github.
- Request [rights to publish your project to Maven Central](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html).

The bit with the request will take around up to a day normally and then you'll be able to publish your code directly to Maven Central.

Comment: May I know what your plugin is for? :)

Comment: it finds the <dependency> information for a jar file instead of user manually searching for the dependency via search.maven.org

Comment: Interesting! Perhaps you would also like to share a link to the project...?

Comment: thanks for your interest, I'll forward you a link once its hosted. which procedure should I follow to release this plugin : http://mojo.codehaus.org/development/performing-a-release.html#Preparing_to_Release or https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide ?

Comment: The Sonatype one, as the other one seems to illustrate things, if you are releasing a new Codehaus project (which you are not doing).

Comment: ok cool, I'll contact you via SO when its open sourced, thanks!