# nexus on tomcat stops responding - alternative to this repository manager

Tags: maven, tomcat, nexus, archiva

Last year I got virtual server for my server needs, configuration is not great, but things work without problem... Few months ago I installed Nexus Repository manager and after that I have daily problem with tomcat... I now restart machine every night, but still it seems that nexus is unavailable most of time.

I am working on OS project and we need to have repository manager (RM) available to host all our stuff and also all libraries our project needs...

I have currently 3 options (how to solve this problem):

1. Downgrading maven version to 1.6 (or at least some that is stable and doesn't need so much resources)
2. Using artifactory (their package seems to be the same size as nexus, but I don't know if it will be better - resource wise)
3. Using archiva (no idea how stable this is and how good it is)

I am thinking about going with option 3, I just don't know if this is right solution. I am sure some of you have your own RM running, what would you recommend? Do you have perhaps any other options? If I use option 1, which version would you recomend...

Thanks in advance,
Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to run Nexus with the native jetty as supplied by the default download bundle instead of on tomcat. This will give you better performance and also better support.

Of course if you can get all libraries into the Central Repository via OSSRH it would be even easier since you could get by without maintaining a repository manager altogether.

Comment: I have installed Archiva and I am running that as standalone application (jetty) and it seems to be working OK, at least for now... But your solution seems like good next step if I am unsatisfied with Archiva and want to switch back to Maven. As for Sonatype, I use to many old non-maven artifacts and when trying to add just one of them I had problems, adding more would be a disaster...  Perhaps I will go that way if I still can't get my own to working somehow.

Answer (score 1):

By `"downgrading Maven version to 1.6"` I assume you're referring to the Java version, as if you're using such an old Nexus, then it doesn't shock me that you're having problems. Upgrade your Java to 1.7.x, as well as your Nexus to the latest one.

Archiva and Artifactory are always options, but I don't think the problem is in Nexus itself, but rather your setup (and you haven't mentioned anything about it).

What version of Java, Nexus, Tomcat are you using?

Also, by `"OS project"`, I assume you mean "OSS" (open source) project. If so, you can use Sonatype's OSS hosting. I've described how to set up an OSS project (using `Github`, `BuildHive` and `Maven Central`) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876211/how-to-opensource-a-maven-plugin/15876923#15876923). You can also just skip to using Maven Central directly, checking [here](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html). I think this would be a better option for you, if you're not familiar enough with managing your own repository manager.

Comment: Actually I am using Nexus 2.8 with tomcat 7 and java 7. But as I said.. after few hours tomcat becomes unresponsive... I got my Sonatype's OSS hosting credentials, but everything I deploy gets stored somewhere where I can't find it (3rd party artifacts not yet in maven), which is why I decided on using my own RM. But I might just take a look at your info... I am currently hosting project on Sourceforge.net.

Comment: Well, it would be great, if you could update your question with some more details like logs around the time it happens, memory usage, etc. Is there a reason you're using it inside your own Tomcat? You can also speak with the Nexus developers by joining their chat here: https://www.hipchat.com/gW26B2y2Z. They would be able to give you some pointers. Why don't you consider using Sonatype's hosting for OSS projects? This way you can also get your artifacts into Maven Central. Nexus is a very stable and reliable piece of software.

Comment: We are using some libraries that are so old that are not on maven (and projects are long dead). I tried to upload them on sonatype and I succeeded, but at end artifacts were never deployed even-though I did everything like it is described in document for deploying 3rd party apps). Since this didn't work my app wouldn't build anyway.

Comment: If you're using sourceforge, I'd strongly recommend considering a switch to Github and following the steps I mentioned concerning how to opensource a Maven plugin (the steps are the same for any other project and are reasonably straight-forward). You can request your own repository with Sonatype's OSS hosting.

Comment: What do you mean they were never uploaded? Uploaded to your own Nexus, or Sonatype's OSS hosting? Could you be a bit more specific what you've done exactly?

Comment: Are you using a repository group? If you are, are you sure it contains all the repositories you need?

Comment: I followed following instructions on how to upload 3rd party artifacts: https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Uploading+3rd-party+Artifacts+to+The+Central+Repository. I could see artifacts were waiting to be accepted, but when doing maven build they were not accessible. So I decided to make my own repository and it worked (at least until I noticed that after few hours of running my nexus was no longer accessible - tomcat restart "fixes" problem. I sceduled daily restart, which made it better, but it seems that daily restart is not enough. Which is why I am looking for another solution.